# Processing array values in bash

Tags: bash, array

I am trying to create an array based upon filenames, and get in trouble with whitespaces. This seems common. But - as far as I can see - the quotes are set correctly, I guess it must be the way the array is built.

```
to_dump="$(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 )"
to_dump_array=($to_dump)

read -p " ->  " final
case "$final" in
   a) for drop in "${to_dump_array[@]}" ;
      do cp "$drop" --recursive --force Destination_Folder && \
      echo "dropped \"$drop\" ;
      done ;;
   b) echo "Won't drop anything" ;;
esac
```

I guess there should be a nicer way to build an array from a find query. Also, where else am I wrong?

Comment: I think thats an extra quote after drop.

Comment: @mikeserv ah yes, that was a typo, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-print0` should not be used in a `$(...)` substitution, because strings in bash variables are null-terminated.

I asked a question whose answer was similar to what this question requires: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469553/1091693

Adapting that answer to your question:

```
to_dump=()
while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
  to_dump+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0)
```

This creates an array called `to_dump` and uses the `read` command to read NULL-delimited elements from `find`. The reason `< <(...)` is being used here rather than a pipe is to avoid an implicit subshell which would prevent the array from being modified.

It's worth noting that your original `find` command probably wants a `-mindepth 1`, or it will pick `.` (the current directory) and you'll end up doing a recursive copy on that.

---

I've noticed you use `-maxdepth 1` as an argument to find, so perhaps this will be more useful:

```
shopt -s nullglob
to_dump=( * .[!.]* ..?* )
```

Avoiding `find`, this uses bash builtins only, doesn't fork, and is for the most part quite clean.

The first line, `shopt -s nullglob`, is a bash(-only) command which turns on the `nullglob` option. This option is described in `man 1 bash`:

> If set, bash allows patterns which match no files (see Pathname Expansion above) to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

In simpler terms, if you type `*` but it doesn't match files, it will remove the `*`. The default behaviour is to put the `*` in there anyway.

The second line adds 3 globs to the array:

- `*`: All files not beginning with `.`
- `.[!.]*`: All files beginning with one `.` and one non-`.` character. This is to avoid matching the `.` and `..` directories.
- `..?*`: All files beginning with `..` and at least one more character. Added for the same reason as the previous glob, covering the cases it missed.

Bash expands the globs into the definition of the array, and it expands them correctly -- no splitting on whitespace or anything like that.

A caveat on the usage of nullglob: If you have nullglob turned on, `curl google.com/search?q=test` will result in curl complaining at you for not passing it arguments, and `ls /var/fasdfasafs*` will give you a listing of the current directory. This is one of the reasons it's not turned on by default.

Comment: Very nice. But could you please explain your "bash builtin" solution a bit more? I think to get most of it, but then, it's just guesswork with missing bits. Thanks!

Comment: I've gone into a little more depth for the pure-bash solution. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Yes, helps a lot! As I'm just getting into shell scripting, this is a very interesting outlook into things to come. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try building the array like this:

```
read -d $'\0' -r -a to_dump <<< $(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0)
```

Comment: I have some problems with that `read` command: `-d '\n'` splits on backslash, not newline (splitting on newline is the default, or you can explicitly do it with `-d $'\n'`). You haven't set `IFS` so it will still do word splitting before it lands in the array. Even with `-a`, `read` stops reading at the delimiter so `read -d $'\n'` will NOT read an entire newline-delimited array. Newline is a valid character in filenames, so this is an unsafe way of getting a list of filenames. You have a `.` at the end of the here-string which will corrupt the last filename.

Comment: You are right of course. I took out the typo and switched it to the null character. Setting or not setting `IFS` does not change the result for me.

Comment: It still has very strange behaviour: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/MMZXMlGzKFa0S3F6H9ma/

Answer (score 1):

```
 find . -maxdepth 1
```

...would appear to me to indicate you want:

```
a=()
for f in ./..?* ./.[!.]* ./*
do  [ -e "$f" ] && a+=$f
done
```

Comment: oh, wow. Yes, somehow. but I want quite more and tried to keep the question simple. But I keep this for later, thanks!

Comment: I edited something similar into my answer, refreshed, and saw your answer - great minds think alike? ;) I have one question though, are you avoiding `nullglob` intentionally or is that a stylistic choice?

Comment: I wasn't aware of `nullglob` until now … this changes things quite a bit … I'll be back later

Comment: @Score_Under - i never use that stuff if it can be helped. It doesn't require much to avoid it, and in doing so you can write code which you can expect to perform much the same in most any shell. I don't  even use shell arrays - i kind of hate names and memory storage and would rather just *process*, but I think that's how the += thing works. If this were my script i wouldn't store anything, the above would be a function, would process args as needed, and return accordingly, This kind of thing aalways seems beside the point.

Comment: @mikeserv Could you plaese explain your solution a bit more? I think to get most of it, but then, it's just guesswork with missing bits. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the script you have is doing what you think it's doing. I don't think that this converts the null terminated output of the find into an bash array of file names:

```
to_dump_array=($to_dump)
```

Have you checked the output of the for loop to see what you're getting?

```
for drop in "${to_dump_array[@]}"
do
    echo -e "$drop\n"
done
```

There's a stack overflow with some suggestions on filling an array from find -print0.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array

You also may be better using the array index to process the array items rather than trying to assign to the variable directly within the for loop, it avoids relying on the shell splitting correctly:

```
for drop in $(seq 0 $((${#to_dump_array[@]} - 1)))
do
    cp "${to_dump_array[$drop]}"
```

This may not be very popular, but if you need to use bash arrays and multiple escapes to manage white space (among other even more unusual characters) in file names then you might be going beyond what the shell was designed for.

You may find something like python, perl, ruby to be faster, more reliable and easier to manage and debug the code base.

I have a number of "red flags" which I use to tell me when I might be going beyond what is wise when shell scripting.

- Multiple levels of escaping or null termination to handle all file name cases.
- Several levels of shell functions calling one another.
- Complex data structures. I.e. going beyond strings, numbers.
- I find myself doing "performance optimisation".
- "Line noise" in expressions.

Yes, you certainly can do all of the above, but should you? Seriously... Python, perl, ruby etc. In python it's this simple, and you don't need to worry about escaping or file names with white space or binary characters.

```
import os

dirListing = os.listdir("somedirectory")

for eachEntry in dirlisting:
    doSomething
```

Comment: Ok, but what in the world is wrong w/ *performance optimization*? Isn't that what programmers are *for*?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with performance optimisation by itself. But If I'm performance optimising a _shell script_, there is almost certainly a "better way".

Comment: Maybe so, but I don't think it's fair to classify *shells* as a lump, especially while you advocate `python` in their stead. `bash` is probably the *slowest* shell of them all - I really do not understand why people use it - but `for drop in $(seq 0 $((${#to_dump_array[@]} - 1)))` that does not help matters. Why  not just count? `x=0; while [ "$((x+=1))" -lt "$#" ]; do ...; done`?

Comment: I think it's fair. If you're worrying about the performance of a shell script you're certainly beyond the optimal usage of the shell language and likely making use of it inappropriately.

Comment: What is *optimal use*? It surely can't be many myriad layers and many hundreds of lines of shell-script *(which is not to mention extremely, elaborately confusing sym-link indirection)* to deal with namespacing issues for an interpreter which was already far too bloated before the schism in the first place, right?  Python has never offered anything of value to me - not since community college - but shell-scripts can be made to work *very* fast in ways Python will never do. A shell can facilitate data flow through pipelines constructed out of *proven, honed tools*. That's powerful.

Comment: Optimal use would be a use case where it was unnecessary to attempt to make performance optimisations to overcome limitations or idiosyncrasies of the language. All tools have an optimal usage envelope, it's usually better to make use of a more appropriate tool than to attempt to force an inappropriate one to serve.

Comment: @mikeserv does the fact that the shell is already running in the background add to the kick it has? Before I get burned: I am just starting with Shell Scripting and have no idea about programming since Commodore BASIC... just asking ;)

Comment: @erch what kick are we talking about here? do you mean, is it because the shell is already running that it can make things work faster? In some cases, yes, but only rarely because most things which the shell can help *kick* will require it to open a new copy of itself for each instance in any case. it isn't really the shell that can be fast - but programs like `sed`, `tr`, `paste` - these are little *command language* modules which a shell can link together in innumerable ways to handle a data stream - and *those programs are **fast***.

Comment: @mikeserv It was a joke on the shall already running, yes

Comment: @mikeserv - gee wiz, me. python did my homework!